# How to pass special character into url in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

In my case, I want to pass data. Example : `#topic_today`, in url `/get-detail/topic/<topic>`

But, in url response bad request. The character `#` can't be read in the url.

My Code:

My Route: `@app.route('/get-detail/topic/<topic>')`

Example Access: `<a href="/get-detail/topic/#topic_today">#topic_today</a>`

Comment: A `#` in a url is special: it indicates a relative position *inside* the current document. You'd have to encode the character to use it "as is". Or avoid it altogether. Your URL would become `/get-detail/topic/%23topic_today`. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding .

Comment: Thanks, this is solve my problem